# issue after upgrade error mounting /dev/sdc2 /media

Tags: mount

I upgraded the software to 22.04 and left one of my internal drives idle for a few months after the upgrade and now when I attempt to mount the drive i receive the above error.

I am able to see the drive in Files and have not tried any fixes as I do not know what to do to fix this issue

The drives are NTFS and I have one other that is able to be mounted , i have changed the drive with the error to the slot the other drive is working from and I still receive the same error so it is not the slot i have it in.

Comment: "*when I attempt to mount the drive*" How exactly do you attempt to mount it? ... Please also add the output of `cat /etc/fstab` and the output of `journalctl --grep='sdc2' --no-pager --since='-1week'` assuming this happened at least once in the past week

Comment: I plugged teh HHD into a slot in the PC , i navigate to the files on the PC and then click on "other locations"and then click the HHD in "on this computer" to load the HHD and i get the error .....                                                                                                                            the first command from your comments did nothing the second one did    -     Aug 08 07:45:36 janice-ProLiant-MicroServer kernel: Buffer I/O error on dev sdc2, logical block 6291465, async page read